# Dynamically set v-model

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make my v-model naming dynamic, but when I run `npm run watch` I get this error

> You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead

and it points to my v-model.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Amount</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr v-for="product in products">
                                                <td>{{ product }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="product" :name="product"> month
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: [],
    data(){
        return {
            products: []
        }
    },
    computed:{

    },
    methods: {
        getProducts(){
            axios.get(`/api/product/all`).then(response => {
               this.products = response.data.products;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The last line of the error clearly states what you can do to fix this. You can't directly modify the contents of an array with v-model
Instead, just make an array of objects like products: [{ name: "" }, { name: "" } ...] and set the v-model to product.name

Comment: Cool thanks. I've adjusted my code to do that.